# Call private method in the same class will raise error on Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

I called a private method in `initialize`, and a no method error was raised. If I comment out the private method, it works fine. I guess I have the wrong concept for using private methods, right?

```
in `initialize': private method `start' called for #<RemoteFocusAutomation::Autofocus:0x007fcfed00a3d8> (NoMethodError)
```

The gist code is here https://gist.github.com/poc7667/7299274

Comment: Don't link to code essential to your question, instead include it in the question. When the link breaks your question will make no sense. " Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 3):

Remove `self` from `self.start(args)` in your `Autofocus#initialize` method definition. You shouldn't call private methods with explicit receiver in ruby. it must be implicit call.

Here is one example:

```
# I tried to call the private method with explicit receiver,which I supposed no to do,
# as Ruby wouldn't allow me,and will give me back error.
class Foo
    def initialize
        self.foo
    end
    private
    def foo;1;end
end

Foo.new
# `initialize': private method `foo' called for # (NoMethodError)
```

Now I am doing what Ruby allow me to do:

```
class Foo
    def initialize
        foo
    end
    private
    def foo;p 1;end
end
Foo.new # => 1 # works!!
```

Comment: It **must** be implicit receiver (not *should*) :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes.. I am not strong with English grammars. :)